# draggable and droppable z-index issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm using drag and drop jquery ui to create form input but there's an issue with z-index while dragging the element is behind the right div but after dropping it's visible. So how to fix this to make elements visible on the right div while dragging

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cgeho8sk/)

in JS

```
$('#main1 div').draggable({
  cursor: 'pointer',
  connectWith: '.dropme2',
  helper: 'clone',
  zIndex: 10
});

$('.dropme2 form').sortable({
  connectWith: '.dropme',
  cursor: 'pointer',
  zIndex: 1000
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="dropme" id="main1">
  <div id="ytvid">YouTube video</div>
  <div id="paragraph">Paragraph</div>
</div>

<div class="dropme2" id="trash">
  <form id="form" style="width: 100%; min-height: 100px; float: left; padding-bottom: 40px; 
    position: relative; z-index: 2;">
    <input type="submit" id="getids" value="save" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 48%;" />
  </form>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#trash,
#main1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
  background: rgb(236, 237, 240);
}
#trash {
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
#main1 {
  float: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  z-index: 9;
}
#main1 div {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  background-color: #7F7F87;
  padding-left: 30px;
  width: 230px;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
#trash form > div {
  height: auto;
  width: 97%;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  background-color: #7F7F87;
  padding-left: 30px;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
.highlight {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px dotted #fff09f;
  background: #fffef5;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue isn't related to the `z-index` property. The reason you are seeing this behavior is because you have `overflow: hidden` set on the container `#trash` and `#main` elements.

The `overflow` property should be set to `visible` (the default) if you want to be able to drag the elements out of their container elements. Therefore you can simply remove `overflow: hidden`.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/p1ss4n0j/)

As a side note, I added `box-sizing: border-box` to the elements in order to include the `padding`/`border` in their width/height calculations. I believe you may have added `overflow: hidden` in order to prevent the elements from extending outside of their parent elements. By adding `box-sizing: border-box`, and giving the elements a width of `100%`, this is resolved.